Abstract algebra question primary module
Suppose that $M$ is an $R$-module.
I will from now on simply use $M$.
Suppose that $N$ is an $R$-submodule such that $N \subseteq M$.
Define (N:M) as the set $\{r \in R | r \cdot M \subseteq N \}$.
Definition of primary module: Suppose that $N \neq M$ and whenever $r \in R, m \in M$ and $r \cdot m \in N$ then $m \in N$ or $r^{k} \in (N:M)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{0}$.
I need to prove that if $N$ is a maximal submodule of $M$, then N is primary.
This is what I have so far. Could anybody give me a hint?
Suppose that $N$ is a maximal submodule of $M$.
The maximality of $N$ implies that $N \neq M$ if there exists another module $K$ s.t. $N \subset K \subset M$ then either $K = N$ or $K = M$.
Notice that $N + R \cdot m$ is a submodule of $M$ for every $m \in M$. (I have proved this somewhere else).
Since $N$ is a maximal submodule of $M$ and $N \subset N+R \cdot m \subset M$, if follows that either $N+R \cdot m = N$ or $N+R \cdot m = M$.
Suppose that $r \cdot m \in N$. And here I'm stuck. I don't really understand how to use the maximality.
I had one idea: Suppose that $N + R \cdot m = N$. This implies that $R \cdot m \subseteq N$, since $N$ is a group. Thus for all $r \in R$, it holds that $r \in (N:M)$. But I'm not sure anymore.
Could I maybe say that $N + R \cdot m = N$ implies that $R \cdot m = \{0 \}?$

Clearly, such a solution has to start from assuming that $rm\in N$. We need to show that $m\in N$ or $r\in\sqrt{(N:M)}$. If $m\in N$ then we are done. Otherwise, we have $N\subsetneq N+R\cdot m$, and so by maximality $N+R\cdot m=M$. It follows that:
$r\cdot M=r\cdot (N+R\cdot m)=r\cdot N+R\cdot (rm)\subseteq N,$
because clearly $r\cdot N\subseteq N$, and $rm\in N$ by assumption. So this shows that in this case even $r$ itself belongs to $(N:M)$.

But I don't understand that if you need to show that $m \in N$ why can you assume $m \in N$?

We don't need to show that. We need to show that either $m\in N$ or $r\in\sqrt{(N:M)}$. Either condition $A$ holds or condition $B$ holds. If $A$ holds then we are done, nothing to show. If it doesn't hold, we show that in this case $B$ must hold. So one of them holds in either case.

Do you know how this kind of logic construction is called in general? I mean that if you need to prove that something has a quality 'a' or 'b' that you can prove this by assuming 'a' holds and proving that if 'a' does not hold then 'b' holds? For some reason, it feels a bit weird to me.
